# Svelte - How to handle prop updates in lifecycles?

Tags: javascript, svelte

If a parent component updates the value of a prop it passes to a child component inside a lifecycle, how can the child use the latest value of that prop in its own lifecycles?

Here's an example where the prop value is undefined in the child component's lifecycles:

`App.svelte`

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import Nested from './Nested.svelte';

    let name;

    onMount(() => {
        name = "world";
    })
</script>

<h1>Hello <Nested name="{name}" /></h1>
```

`Nested.svelte`

```html
<script>
    import { onMount, afterUpdate } from 'svelte';

    export let name;

    onMount(() => {
        console.log("mount name:", name);
    })

    afterUpdate(() => {
        console.log("after update name:", name);
    })
</script>

<span>{name}</span>
```

https://svelte.dev/repl/65ac3d9c3913408bad459e2ad2a27d8e?version=3.4.2

If I await `tick`, the latest value is available in the lifecycles, but I'm not sure if that's the right way to handle it:

`App.svelte`

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import Nested from './Nested.svelte';

    let name;

    onMount(() => {
        name = "world";
    })
</script>

<h1>Hello <Nested name="{name}" /></h1>
```

`Nested.svelte`

```html
<script>
    import { onMount, afterUpdate, tick } from 'svelte';

    export let name;

    onMount(async () => {
        await tick();
        console.log("mount name:", name);
    })

    afterUpdate(async () => {
        await tick();
        console.log("after update name:", name);
    })
</script>

<span>{name}</span>
```

https://svelte.dev/repl/9e66f312a17d41a8adf6e3e3b95c5327?version=3.4.2

Answer (score 0):

There's no logical situation where anyone would set the state **synchronously** in `onMount` hook like the way you did, because if you want it to be there when it's mounted, you should set it in `let name = 'world';`

A logical situation would be setting the state **asynchoronously** in `onMount` hook (for e.g., make an ajax request and set the ajax response value to a state).

if you try to simulate an asynchoronous operation like this

```
// App.svelte
onMount(() => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        name = "world";
    },0)
})
```

things works without needing to use `tick()`. `afterUpdate` hook receives the updated value as expected.

https://svelte.dev/repl/9e0411ed66e34e2e8ac1937e41b2709a?version=3.4.2

Comment: For more context, I have a component that receives a `Date` instance as a prop. I am statically rendering my Svelte app, so in order to avoid baking the date into the static rendering, I want to defer initializing it until the client-side render, which is why I'm setting the prop synchronously in `onMount`.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

If you need to run logic *specifically* in the `onMount` lifecycle method of your *child* component, then adding `await tick()` to that method – as you have shown in your question – is your only option.

And if you're going to do that, then you may as well keep it consistent and apply the same fix to your `afterUpdate` lifecycle method too.

---

**Full Answer**

I suspect that part of the problem you're encountering may be related to [this open issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3290), detailing how `afterUpdate` is sometimes not being called.

Pending a fix for that issue (if it is indeed related), there are a few ways you could solve your immediate problem, depending on your requirements:

- Instead of `name = "world"`, do `setTimeout(() => name = "world")`, as suggested by @jacob-goh
- Instead of using `afterUpdate`, use `beforeUpdate`
- Add `await tick()` to your lifecycle methods, as you have shown in your question

A downside to the first two options is that `name` will still be undefined in the `onMount` function of your child – this is because the parent's `onMount` is called *after* the child's (and it looks like this was [a relatively recent, intentional change](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/3150)). So if you need to run your logic specifically when the child is mounted, you'd be fresh out of luck.

Another downside to the second option is that `beforeUpdate`, as the name implies, is triggered *before* changes have been applied to the DOM. So if you need access to the updated DOM, again you'd be fresh out of luck.

The third option doesn't have either of those issues, but as you alluded to in your original question, it's a bit...odd, and would presumably become somewhat redundant once a fix for the underlying issue (again, if indeed that open issue I linked is relevant) has been implemented.

That being said, regardless of the state of that issue, the third option is the only option which enables you to access the updated `name` in the child's `onMount` method.

The reason that adding `await tick()` works is because you end up deferring your child's lifecycle logic until *after* the latest batch of changes has been applied. This means for example that the parent's `onMount` lifecycle method will have completed *before* the tick has resolved, allowing the child's `onMount` lifecycle method to see the newly updated value of `name`.